# How to get Next.js and redux-api to work (with next-redux-wrapper)

Tags: javascript, redux, next.js, redux-api-middleware

I’m struggling to get server-side rendering (SSR) to work with [`redux-api`](https://github.com/lexich/redux-api/issues/183). The app works fine with just client-side rendering (CSR).

For SSR to work, I need the data to be available in Next.js’ `getInitialProps` function. I’m trying to use [`next-redux-wrapper`](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/with-redux) to bind it together.

Current status:

```
class ShowLessonPage extends React.Component {

    static async getInitialProps ({store, isServer, pathname, query}) {
        console.log(`getInitialProps`, {store, isServer, pathname, query});
        const { dispatch } = store;
        const lessonSlug = query.lessonSlug;
        // Get one Lesson
        dispatch(reduxApi.actions.oneLesson({ id: `slug=${lessonSlug}` }));
    }

    render() {
        console.log('render', this.props.oneLesson);
        const lesson = this.props.oneLesson.data;
        //...
    }

    //.....

}

const createStoreWithThunkMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk)(createStore);
const reducer = combineReducers(myReduxApi.reducers); // redux-api

const makeStore = function (state, enhancer) {
    return createStoreWithThunkMiddleware(reducer, state);
}

const mapStateToProps = function (state) {
    return { oneLesson: state.oneLesson };
};

// withRedux = next-redux-wrapper
const ShowLessonPageConnected = withRedux({ createStore: makeStore, mapStateToProps: mapStateToProps })(ShowLessonPage)
export default ShowLessonPageConnected;
```

I at least get `store` into `getInitialProps` now, but I get a strange `Error: only absolute urls are supported` message that I didn’t have in my CSR (pre-`withRedux`) version of the app. And `this.props.oneLesson.data` is of course empty.

`makeStore` is getting a `state`=`undefined` on the server generated calls, maybe that’s a clue.

I’m also open to replacing `redux-api` with something else that works similarly.

**UPDATE 1:** by making all URLs full, Redux is now hitting my API endpoint. However, for 1 page reload it calls `makeStore` no less than 3 times, and only the first call contains the correct slug, see console output:

```
makeStore { state: undefined, reqParams: { lessonSlug: 'tyrannosaurus-rex' } }
getInitialProps { query: { lessonSlug: 'tyrannosaurus-rex' } }
API: GET request: { _id: 'slug=tyrannosaurus-rex' }
makeStore { state: undefined, reqParams: { lessonSlug: 'undefined' } }
getInitialProps { query: { lessonSlug: 'undefined' } }
API: GET request: { _id: 'slug=undefined' }
makeStore { state: undefined, reqParams: { lessonSlug: 'undefined' } }
getInitialProps { query: { lessonSlug: 'undefined' } }
API: GET request: { _id: 'slug=undefined' }
```

**UPDATE 2:** A breakthrough: returning a promise from `getInitialProps` makes SSR work. Now client-side rendering is acting up, funny enough.

```
static async getInitialProps ({store, isServer, pathname, query}) {
    const { dispatch } = store;
    const lessonSlug = query.lessonSlug;
    const resultPromise = await dispatch(reduxApi.actions.oneLesson({ id: `slug=${lessonSlug}` }));
    return resultPromise;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve it, after a full day’s hair-pulling.

There was a number of issues before it worked as it should:

1. Absolute URLs. The client-only code had no issue with relative URLs, but the server did.
2. `getInitialProps` must return a Promise to the results (see below).
3. My data object (`oneLesson`) ended up on `this.state`, not `this.props` as I expected (for my use case I don’t really care as long as I can render it both on server and client).

Here’s the final version of `getInitialProps`:

```
static async getInitialProps ({store, isServer, pathname, query}) {
    const { dispatch } = store;
    const lessonSlug = query.lessonSlug;
    const resultPromise = await dispatch(reduxApi.actions.oneLesson({ id: `slug=${lessonSlug}` }));
    return resultPromise;
}
```

Here’s a complete working example of Next.js, redux-api, and next-redux-wrapper working in harmony:

https://github.com/tomsoderlund/nextjs-express-mongoose-crudify-boilerplate